# Multidisciplinary function handle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

I want to know is it possible to make multidisciplinary function handle in MATLAB and if possible, how can I do this.

Comment: Is it possible to define what a multidisciplinary function handle is?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a "multivariate function" since a "multidisciplinary function" is completely non-nonsensical.

```
f=@(x,y)x+y
f(3,2)
ans =
     5
```

Comment: You can shave off 2 bytes by removing the unnecessary parentheses.